# Unknown Parsing error for less than operator for number fields

Tags: soql

I have a simple query where there 2 number fields Total_Amount__c and Value__c but when i want to query
in console it is throwing an unknown parsing error not able to understand what is the issue exactly here

```
select id,Total_Amount__c,Value__c from account where Total_Amount__c <= Value__c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We cannot have an SObject field on the right-hand side of an expression in SOQL, data binding nonwithstanding.

The point is that things like `WHERE Field1 <some comparison operator> Field2` are not syntactically valid.

You'll either need to do that comparison in Apex (with the results of the query), or add a formula field in your object to do the comparison for you (you can then put, say, `Formula_Comparing_2_Fields__c = true` into your query, which ends up having a similar effect)

Comment: @Darek F Thanks for your update i have changed the logic as per your suggestion.